# Does there exist any commercial WPF control similar to the recipient TextBox in Outlook 2010?

Tags: wpf, textbox, outlook, controls

our company wants a TextBox very similar to outlook recipient Textbox.
Not emails but displaying people`s names delimited with a e.g. semicolon and
even more crazy ideas on it...

Do you know of any commercial WPF control who can handle that job? I already checked DX,Telerik,Infrapistics,Farpoint,componentone,Nevron,Syncfusion, etc...

OpenSource is no choice for us.

Answer (score -4):

Is there a commercial TextBox that implements your company's completely unspecified requirements?  I think it is safe to say that the answer is no.

Comment: would you have answered if I post 100 lines here?

Comment: If you had posted a question that could be answered, yes.

Comment: Your question is fine, I understand what you asked for. As of now, I did not found something, have you?